# How to solve lack of promise unwrapping when writing nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I've got a few nested directives:

```
<first-directive>
  <second-directive user="user">
    <third-directive name="name">
      <fourth-directive description="description">
```

The template of the first directive has the second directive, template of the second directive has the third directive and so on. All directives have isolated scopes.

The first directive sets `user` object on its own scope. If it does it in an synchronous way (`$scope.user = {name: "Alice"}`, then everything is fine. However, if it loads user in an asynchronous way (e.g. `$http.get(url).then(function (user) { $scope.user = user }`), then all other directives won't work, because e.g. when the controller function of the second directive is evaluated, `user` hasn't been set yet on its scope.

The only solution I've found so far is to use `$scope.$watch` in all nested promises (e.g. `$scope.$watch("user", function (user) { $scope.name = user.name}` for the second promise), which sucks a lot, because if I want to use directive that I already use somewhere else inside `<first-directive>`, I need to rewrite it to use `$scope.$watch` as well...

Is there any other way to fix it? I know that I could load data necessary for the first directive e.g. in `resolve` function of the route it's used in, but I'd like to be able to put this directive in any page without modifying any routes or controllers.

Comment: Why dont you resolve the user in route instead of fetching the user in controller?

Comment: I'm fetching the object in directive's controller, not route's controller. I want to create an independent component that can be put on any page and it will fetch the data it needs by itself. If there's no way to make it work without adding $scope.$watch everywhere, I'll probably end up fetching data in routes the component is used in, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure it fits your use case, but if the first directive always loads the user asynchronously it can use `ng-if` in it's template:

```
template: '<second-directive ng-if="user" user="user"></second-directive>'
```

This way the second directive will not be compiled until the user is actually available (nor will the third or fourth directive).

This also makes it possible to use other directives in the chain without having to add `$watch`.

And if you need to use the second directive somewhere else where the user is already available you can just use it without the `ng-if`.